# MySQL multiple count by one query

Tags: php, mysql, count, pivot, where-clause

I try to count how many were sold by the month and get one Array.

```
$q = SELECT COUNT(id) AS January FROM tableName WHERE status='sold' AND month = '1'
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(id) AS February FROM tableName WHERE status='sold' AND month = '2'

$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, $q));

print_r($row);
```

UNION don't work, when I'm trying print_r(array), I get result

```
[Jenuary] => 200
```

How do I get one array in both months?

I want result:

```
[January] => 200,
[February] => 221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(month = 1) as january, sum(month = 2) as february
from tablename
where status = 'sold' and month in (1, 2)
```

This generates just one row, with two columns called `january` and `february`, each containing the number of rows for that month.

Or maybe you want one row per month. In that case you can use simple aggregation:

```
select month, count(*) cnt
from tablename
where status = 'sold' and month in (1, 2)
group by month
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query to get exact result you want.

```
select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')) as month, count(*) cnt
from tablename
where status = 'sold'
group by month
```

Only for specific month

```
 select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month, '%m')) as month, count(*) cnt
    from tablename
    where status = 'sold' and month in(1, 2)
    group by month
```

Comment: first answer already fix my problem,  thank you too..